# Default value of style.filter in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

Hey, quite a quick question, I just wondered what `element.style.filter` returns in Internet Explorer if you have not touched it. Is it `undefined`, `false` or something else?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe it to be an empty sting after a bit more research, is this correct?

Comment: Got it, it is equal to '0'. Thats right, a string containing 0, how odd.

Comment: heh, "odd" is nothing unusual when it comes to IE.  :-)

Comment: Good point, just in the console it equals '' and in JavaScript it equals '0', well done Microsoft, another great achievement to add to your list. (is oozing sarcasm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my comments state, I worked it out. This is the best way of explaining it.

```
element.style.filter == '0';
```

So a string containing 0.

Comment: glad you managed to answer your own question. please mark your answer as "accepted" so that other people searching for this topic can find it (and also so it stops appearing in the unanswered questions list). Thank you!

Comment: Yep, will do, although I can't for another two days, I will mark it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is empty string value. you can check it by executing the below code

```
alert(document.getElementById("elementId").style.filter=="")
```

Comment: Yep I tried that, it is actually equal to a string containing 0. Although it comes up as containing nothing under a console.